# Firebase auth with android things for real-time database

Tags: firebase, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Is it possible to store data according to user who is using to real-time database from raspberry pi 3 on android things. 
I want to achieve data structure in below way:-

```
Users {
        User1 : "base64 image1",
        User2 : "base64 image2",
.................
      }
```

This `user1` and `user2` should be decided bases on the user who is using the raspberry pi.
I want to achieve this through android code.
I researched over it.. making Firebase rule public and using using anonymous auth are two things I got.. What can be best way security wise to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

unless you have some way for them to sign in ( a screen )

or they sign in on another device (an android app) and you send the credentials over the RPi

Then Firebase Anonymous auth is your best bet, allowing sign in without user interaction. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth.

The good thing about anon auth is, if you change your mind later and add a screen / a companion app, you can keep the user data

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed up to your app to work with data protected by security rules. If an anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, you can link their sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue to work with their protected data in future sessions.

Comment: If i make a companion app for android where user can authenticate himself how i should send this data to specific raspberry pi (Or the android things device) the user might have bought.

Comment: Pairing the device with an Android app is an option. But how will the IoT device and the Android app know that they belong to each other in that case?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am thinking to use android uuid for identifying the raspberry pi. With the device i will be having a qr code having details of the uuid for the device. When user using the device scan it. It will fetch the details and send it to Firebase with the user id from the companion app.